# What is the problem in the satellite data of MH370

Tags: accidents, mh370-incident

In the Inmarsat data of MH370, there are handshakes (BTO) with time (UTC) at: 19:41, 20:41, 21:41, 22:41, 00:11,00:19. Normally it pinged every hour, but why the 2nd to last happened at 00.11 that was 1.5 hour after the previous one? The last one happened at 00:19 is for what reason?

Also can ping be stopped manually, e.g. by turning off the power, then there will be no ping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [explained back in 2014](https://www.nbcnews.com/storyline/missing-jet/satellite-handshakes-data-missing-jet-released-n115001) when the data was released. It is consistent with a loss of power due to fuel exhaustion, followed by battery power restoring communication.

Comment: And the lack of signal after 00:19 indicates that the batteries were also dead by that time.